# “His swimming is brilliant”

Tags: gerunds, gerund-clauses, possessive-adjectives

Can we say:

> - His swimming is brilliant

I made up this sentence to examine:

1) if  i can use possessive adjectives before gerund.

2) and if a gerund can stand by its own without an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**His swimming** is brilliant.

Although the word **swimming** is a gerund, it's best to call its grammatical use here a **noun** or **gerund noun**.

That makes everything easier. Just like you can say: "**My car** is nice.", you can say: "But **my driving** is lousy." Car and driving are nouns.

As for a noun without an object, bear in mind that verbs have objects (He **played the song**.), not nouns. Nouns don't have objects.

Most nouns can take possessives. And gerunds used as nouns (not adjectives) can also.

Reminder: gerunds can be nouns or adjectives.